# How to configure a maven webapp project to have the same structure that we have in the source code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, web-deployment, jsf-2.2

When we deploy an application to an application server like Wildfly, Tomcat, etc, it puts all of our source code on a folder named **classes** inside the **WEB-INF** folder.

Using Eclipse, we can change this folder destination on the *Deployment Assembly* menu, inside the project properties menu.

But I would like to do an configuration to use the same structure that we have in the real project (not in the deployed one). For example, on a maven project, we have an structure like

```
myproject/src/main/java/com/mydomain/myproject/model/controller/mb/IndexMB.java
```

So, how can we have a structure like

```
myproject.war/WEB-INF/src/main/java/com/mydomain/myproject/controller/mb/IndexMB.class
```

in the deployed project?

Looks like the files destination could be achieved changing the destinations on the Deployment Assembly menu, but unfortunally the managed bean could not be instantied or called.

How can we perform this?

**Motivations**

Or OCDs =)

- I'm creating a class, named Router, that will be very important and essential to the system. This class will provide the routes for all system folders and packages. I will use this class to configure database connections, log4j, prettyfaces, and so on. So, for example, if I put the `log4j.properties` file in `src/main/resource/configuration/logger/log4j.properties`, I will use the Router class like `new File(Router.getInstance().get('src.main.resource'),'configuration/logger/log4j.properties')`. This class will be essential and a workaround could be done, to find the files even on a deployed or non-deployed system, but keep the things with the same hierarchy would be awesome.
- I would like to keep the things organized and I would like to control where each created file will be put and find a way to use it programatically, if needed. Just put all files on the root folder (even on the non deployed version) looks very messy to me. For example put the log4j.properties in the root, etc.
- Change the default behavior. If I have a source folder, that not contains java classes, like images, properties files, json files; these aren't **classes**, so, these should not be in the classes folder. I think the best way is to configure to each file to be deployed on a proper folder and the system learns how to get and operate with it.
- The Router class will be used on application servers (that see the deployed folders) and in java applications and junit tests, so keep it together will be prefereable.

Comment: Then your application **would *not*** work. **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: I agree with @ElliottFrisch. That structure is just how Maven projects work. Is it your triggering your OCD or is there a deeper reason you want to modify its structure?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, JeffDiederiks, I added some motivations =)

Comment: Even if you changed the way maven packaged the code, you couldn't change the way a Java app server deploys a WAR file (the layout of a WAR file is specified by the JEE spec).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I can change the way that a Java app server deploys a WAR file changing it on the Deployment Assembly. But, I dont know if we change it, putting the classes in other folder, for example, could we teach the java app server, maybe throught some configuration in the project, to search the classes inside the new folder.

Comment: No. That's why I said your application **would *not*** work.